# Parsing throuth complex xml with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file with structure like this:

```
<categories>
 <category>
   <id></id>
   <name></name>
 </category>
   ...
</categories>
<products>
 <product>
   <id></id>
   <name></name>
 </product>
   ...
</products>
<params>
 <param>
   <id></id>
   <name></name>
 </param>
   ...
</params>
<product_params>
 <product_param>
   <param_id></param_id>
   <product_id></product_id>
 </product_param>
   ...
</product_params>
```

How do I display product nodes, right category (that matches id) and all params for that product?

I tried doing something like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$products = $xml->products;
$product_params = $xml->product_params->product_param;

foreach ($products->product as $product) {

   echo '<p>'.$product->name.'</p>';

 for($i=0; $i < count($product_params) ;$i++) {

    if($product->id == $product_params[$i]->product_id) {

    }
 }

 }
```

The file is too big and script crashes. Plus with my "solution" I would need at least one more loop nested in there.

Comment: a.1) Parse and denormalize structure so it is easier/faster to search might have duplicated data. a.2) Parse push to DB use db for search. b) Try to use xpath quires http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php might help but would depend on file size.   How big of XML we talking about?

Comment: File is about 700MB.

Comment: I would push it to DB.

Comment: How do the IDs match? Better yet can you provide desired results?

Comment: I'll push to DB. Should be quick. Thanks for help.